# How can i reduce number of models into one model in rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I reduce the number of models into one model in  rails project

I have 7 models

1) Agriculture,
2) Apparel,
3) Sports,
4) Automobiles, 
5) Computer, 
6) Electronics, 
7) Electrical,
I want to reduce into one model called "industry"

Comment: Why would you want to? Is their data similar? What about their public methods?

Comment: Why did you want to reduce model?

Comment: If I had to choose between "too much models" and "not enough models", I would go for the "too much models" issue. From the examples you gave, all of those models are defining a different kind of object (Agriculture has not much in common with Sports or Automobiles). If your concern is about code beeing duplicated between those X models, then use shared `module`s and define behavior in them instead of using inheritance (dependency injection vs inheritance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend keeping them all different models and just namespacing them under Industry.  For example running: `rails g model Industry/Automobile` would setup an industry folder in your model with an Automobile model.  You'd then look up records with the namespace such as:  `first_car = Industry::Autmobile.first` etc.  Since you've already created your models you can namespace them manually.

Answer (score 1):

You might check out [polymorphic associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) and Single Table Inheritance or [STI](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html)

STI can have problems, especially if the different types of records differ a lot, so do some research on the drawbacks before using it.

Comment: Polymorphic associations are great, until the moment your app is big enough to make you feel bad about using it: no association preload, no `foreign key` in the database (only on the rails level), etc. It is a very nice feature but has its limitations, especially for big projects which have to scale